# Send meeting invitation on macOS Calendar from no-Apple-Mail client

Tags: macos, icloud, calendar

I manage my iCloud calendar through the Calendar app on macOS. When I invite people to a meeting in my "Home" calendar they don't get a meeting invitation.

I'm wondering why. Does it have anything to do with the fact that I don't use Apple Mail as my mail client.

**Setup**

- iCloud for calendar and contacts, I don't use iCloud for email
- iCloud email is forwarded to my own domain
- iCloud calendar loaded into Calendar app
- Thunderbird to manage my non-iCloud email

**Behavior**

I understand that the Calendar can't automagically use my Thunderbird email account to send out meeting invitations. However, I would expect it to use the iCloud email service to do so. I don't see any invitations in the iCloud "sent items", though.

Comment: How are you inviting people?

Comment: I add their email address into the "Add invitees" field. If I later open the event on the iPhone (same iCloud calendar) and hit "Resend invitation" or so the invitation _is_ being set.

Comment: [What happens if I attempt to send an invitation from the Calendar app to an email address that doesn't have an associated Apple ID?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/364305/what-happens-if-i-attempt-to-send-an-invitation-from-the-calendar-app-to-an-emai) I do use apple mail.