# What happens if I attempt to send an invitation from the Calendar app to an email address that doesn't have an associated Apple ID?

Tags: apple-id, calendar, notifications

If I have a standard IMAP mail account set as my default on an iOS device and I then attempt to send somebody an invetation from the Calendar app, what happens if the recipient doesn't have an Apple ID - *how will the invitation appear to them?*

No documentation that I could find online makes reference to this situation; the only things I could find were concerning sending invitations to existing Apple IDs (at which point a notification is generated on the device itself), or about using Exchange Accounts - which again works differently. My assumption was that Apple must send an email of some kind to the invitee, but I want to get it tested.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just tried with one of my friends' email. They receive the mail with buttons like accept, decline etc., and the info of the event of course. The said buttons have URL like: `https://www.icloud.com/calendar/eventreply_full/en-gb/<some Key>&cc=IN#reply=accept` It was sent from `noreply@email.apple.com` but with my name in the *Sender*.

`.ics` of the event, text and HTML files were also attached.

Comment: Thanks for testing - out of interest, would you be able to provide an example URL for one of the buttons? Does it redirect back to an iCloud server? Main reason for not testing was that I don't have an example email address that I can use.

Comment: `https://www.icloud.com/calendar/eventreply_full/en-gb/<some Key>&cc=IN#reply=accept`

Comment: @elliott94 Why though? I am curious

Comment: No documentation that I could find online makes reference to this situation; the only things I could find were concerning sending invitations to existing Apple IDs (at which point a notification is generated on the device itself), or about using Exchange Accounts - which again works differently. My assumption was that Apple must send an email of some kind to the invitee, but I just wanted to get this confirmed as a definite. :)