# Calendar invite sends email to one address and invite to another

Tags: calendar

When I send my partner an iPad calendar invite to one email address she gets a Calendar invite, but if I send the invite another address (a gmail one) she gets an email message. How can I set up calendar so both are calendar invites?

Comment: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/364305/what-happens-if-i-attempt-to-send-an-invitation-from-the-calendar-app-to-an-emai/364309#364309